# Tinted background image with linear-gradient

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to overlay linear-gradient on a background image WHEN the background image is not set in CSS?

This is my generated markup and I can't change it:

```
<div class="card bg-inverse">
   <img class="card-img" src="img/major-search-result.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
   <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
      <h4 class="card-title">Accounting</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to make the background image slightly tinted. I know it can be done if the background image is also set in CSS like this:

```
.tinted-image {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(image.jpg);
}
```

But what if the background image cannot be set in CSS and generated by the CMS? Is it possible to ONLY set the `linear-gradient` with CSS and not the actual background image?